# Extends class makes ajax call

Tags: ajax, inheritance, extjs

I am very new to ExtJS 4 and I have a problem extending a class. I have these files:

*UsersWindow.js*

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.UserModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    /* ... */
}

Ext.define('MyDesktop.UsersWindow', {
    /* ... */
}
```

*DealersWindow.js*

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.DealerModel', {
    extend: 'MyDesktop.UserModel',
    /* ... */
}

Ext.define('MyDesktop.DealersWindow', {
    extend: 'MyDesktop.UsersWindow',
    /* ... */
}
```

When I run the application, everything works as expected, however, I have this ajax call:

```
/UserModel.js?_dc=1379135132790
```

that gives a 404, and then a error parsing the javascript. I want to understand why ExtJS making this call ? Does every class should be in there own file ? Can I configure ExtJS to no look for this file ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: change your model class name 'MyDesktop.UserModel' to 'MyDesktop.model.UserModel' and rename your file with name "UserModel" same in "DealerModel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every class has to be in its own file for the Ext Loader to work properly. Beside, the name of the file should be the same as the class, and its path should match the namespace.

What happens here is that the `extend: 'MyDesktop.UserModel'` line prompts the `Ext.Loader` to load the `UserModel` class, that it expects to find in the `UserModel.js` file in the root path for the `MyDesktop` namespace, which seems to be configured as the root directory of the application...

You can configure root source directories for different namespaces with the [`paths`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths) property of the `Loader`, or the [one of the `Application`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-paths).

If you want to prevent Ext from trying to load this file, you will have to [disable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-enabled) the Loader, and then you will have to include all your source files as `<script>` tags in your HTML. I think this will also make it impossible to compile a production build of the application later.

Alternatively, you could put your definition of `MyDesktop.UserModel` **above** the definition of `MyDesktop.DealerModel`, either in the same file or a file before it in the script tags. Note that even this may not work, because the `requires` option in your classes definitions may change the order in which the class definition are actually executed. Then again, that will probably break the build process ultimately...

In short, you should not try to work again the framework's expectations. Especially when you consider that the 1:1 mapping between class names and the file system is standard practice in about every OO language out there...

Comment: Thanks, I put UserModel in its file and its works. I didn't put DealerModel in its file because I don't get any error. I guess it is because there is not "Extends" of the DealerModel class

Comment: You should get the habit to have one class per file right now, if you want to build your application with Ext's compiler one day.